# What is the probability that the newest of the first edition is next to the oldest of the second edition?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are six copies of a certain textbook in a school library.

They were all purchased at different times.

3 are of the first edition and the other 3 are second edition.

They have been returned in a random order.

They are all on a shelf.

What is the probability that the newest of first edition is next to the oldest of the second edition?

Please explain your answer. I understand it will involve some interesting counting methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider all possible placements of two particular books among six spots - these number $\binom{6}{2}=15$. Since $5$ of them correspond to the two particular books being next to each other, the final probability is $\dfrac{5}{15}=\dfrac{1}{3}$.

Comment: I like this reasoning. My way of doing it is too time consuming this makes a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Call these books A and B. Book A is either at an end of the shelf (with probability $\frac13$) or not (with probability $\frac23$). If Book A is at the end of the shelf, then Book B is next to it with probability $\frac15$; if not, then Book B is next to it with probability $\frac25$. So the probability is
$$\frac13\cdot\frac15 + \frac23\cdot\frac25 = \frac13$$

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got it. Tell me if you think my reasoning is correct.

Say let's

1) take these 2 unique books out and place the other 4. (4!)

2) Now there are 5 positions in between those 4. 'B'B'B'B' (5C1)

3) Now we sort the two books that we placed in one of those positions next to each other. (2!)

4! x 5C1 x 2! = 240

P(E) = 240 / 6!

= 240 / 720

= 1/3

Comment: Your method is correct, though you don't really need to consider all of the arrangements of the other $4$ books. For an answer which uses a similar idea to the one you have used, see my answer, and for a different approach, see TonyK's answer.

Comment: Yeah. I like your approach :) thanks. We just learned counting methods before probability but I need to get used to working with probabilities without first working out the number of ways that something can happen first. It's good that I can do it though.

Comment: Glad to help :)